# Join two Spark mllib pipelines together

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have two separate `DataFrames` which each have several differing processing stages which I use `mllib` transformers in a pipeline to handle.

I now want to join these two pipelines together, keeping the features (columns) from each `DataFrame`.

Scikit-learn has the `FeatureUnion` class for handling this, and I can't seem to find an equivalent for `mllib`.

I can add a custom transformer stage at the end of one pipeline that takes the DataFrame produced by the other pipeline as an attribute and join it in the transform method, but that seems messy.

Comment: is it a join or a union you are looking for? both can be handled using dataframes.

Comment: @jamborta it was a join, however, I wanted to do it as a pipeline stage so that I would have schema checking along my entire pipeline

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Pipeline` or `PipelineModel` are valid `PipelineStages`, and as such can be combined in a single `Pipeline`. For example with:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1.0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
    (0.0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
], ("label", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"))

pipeline1 = Pipeline(stages=[
    VectorAssembler(inputCols=["x1", "x2"], outputCol="features1")
])

pipeline2 = Pipeline(stages=[
    VectorAssembler(inputCols=["x3", "x4"], outputCol="features2")
])
```

you can combine `Pipelines`:

```
Pipeline(stages=[
    pipeline1, pipeline2, 
    VectorAssembler(inputCols=["features1", "features2"], outputCol="features")
]).fit(df).transform(df)
```

```
+-----+---+---+---+---+---------+---------+-----------------+
|label|x1 |x2 |x3 |x4 |features1|features2|features         |
+-----+---+---+---+---+---------+---------+-----------------+
|1.0  |0  |1  |1  |0  |[0.0,1.0]|[1.0,0.0]|[0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0]|
|0.0  |1  |0  |0  |1  |[1.0,0.0]|[0.0,1.0]|[1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]|
+-----+---+---+---+---+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

or pre-fitted `PipelineModels`:

```
model1 = pipeline1.fit(df)
model2 = pipeline2.fit(df)

Pipeline(stages=[
    model1, model2, 
    VectorAssembler(inputCols=["features1", "features2"], outputCol="features")
]).fit(df).transform(df)
```

```
+-----+---+---+---+---+---------+---------+-----------------+
|label| x1| x2| x3| x4|features1|features2|         features|
+-----+---+---+---+---+---------+---------+-----------------+
|  1.0|  0|  1|  1|  0|[0.0,1.0]|[1.0,0.0]|[0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0]|
|  0.0|  1|  0|  0|  1|[1.0,0.0]|[0.0,1.0]|[1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]|
+-----+---+---+---+---+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

So the approach I would recommend is to join data beforehand, and `fit` and `transform` a whole `DataFrame`.

See also:

- [Apack Spark add new fitted stage to a exitsting PipelineModel without fitting again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53269075/6910411)

Comment: Here we have single dataframe, but let say if we have two different dataframes with different number of rows, how spark ml pipeline join these internally? Is it a cross join or some other?

Comment: Is there any performance difference between using 2 pipelines separately vs using one single pipeline?