# Add new fitted stage to a exitsting PipelineModel without fitting again

Tags: apache-spark, pipeline, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-2.0

I would like to concatenate several trained Pipelines to one, which is similar to 
"[Spark add new fitted stage to a exitsting PipelineModel without fitting again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49337830/spark-add-new-fitted-stage-to-a-exitsting-pipelinemodel-without-fitting-again)" however the solution as below is for PySpark.

```py
> pipe_model_new = PipelineModel(stages = [pipe_model , pipe_model2])
> final_df = pipe_model_new.transform(df1)
```

In Apache Spark 2.0 "PipelineModel"'s constructor is marked as private, hence it can not be called outside. While in "Pipeline" class, only "fit" method creates "PipelineModel"

```scala
val pipelineModel =  new PipelineModel("randomUID", trainedStages)
val df_final_full = pipelineModel.transform(df)
```

> ```
> Error:(266, 26) constructor PipelineModel in class PipelineModel cannot be accessed in class Preprocessor
>     val pipelineModel =  new PipelineModel("randomUID", trainedStages)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing* wrong [with using `Pipeline`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44573098/6910411) and invoking `fit` method. If a stage is a `Transfomer`, and `PipelineModel` is**, `fit` works like identity.

You can check [relevant Python](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5264164a67df498b73facae207eda12ee133be7d/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py#L105-L107):

```py
if isinstance(stage, Transformer):
    transformers.append(stage)
    dataset = stage.transform(dataset)
```

and [Scala code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5264164a67df498b73facae207eda12ee133be7d/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/Pipeline.scala#L154-L155):

This means that fitting process will only validate the schema and create a new `PipelineModel` object.

```py
case t: Transformer =>
  t
```

---

* The only possible concern is presence of non-lazy `Transformers`, though, with exception to deprecated `OneHotEncoder`, Spark core API doesn't provide such.

** In Python:

```py
from pyspark.ml import Transformer, PipelineModel

issubclass(PipelineModel, Transformer)
```

```
True
```

In Scala

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf
import org.apache.spark.ml._

typeOf[PipelineModel] <:< typeOf[Transformer]
```

```
Boolean = true
```

Comment: I don't understand how you solve the question. Any example to achieve `val pipelineModel =  new PipelineModel("randomUID", trainedStages)` ?

Comment: Because I have similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69891877/can-i-alter-spark-pipeline-stages-by-some-trained-transfomers