# Can I alter spark Pipeline stages by some trained transfomers?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Because I need alter train data after StringIndexer. (append unseen future to handle error when future model prediction) . So I need build a pipeline by trained Transfomers.

But I haven't find a way to do this thing ,
sample code:

```
// fit by original df
val catIndexer = catFeatures.map(cname => {
  new StringIndexer()
    .setHandleInvalid("keep")  // would get error when future prediction if training data doesn't contain unseen feature
    .setInputCol(cname)
    .setOutputCol(cname + KeyColumns.stringIndexerSuffix)
})
val indexedCatFeatures = catIndexer.map(idx => idx.getOutputCol)

val stringIndexerPipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(catIndexer)
val stringIndexerPipelineFitted = stringIndexerPipeline.fit(trainDataset)  // note: trainDataset

// transform original df with one new row(unseen feature), to avoid unseen feature when future prediction
val rdd = mdContext.get.spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(List(Row(newRow:_*)))
val newDF = mdContext.get.spark.createDataFrame(rdd, trainDataset.schema).na.fill(0)
val patchedTrainDataset = trainDataset.unionByName(newDF)
val strIndexTrainDataset = stringIndexerPipelineFitted.transform(patchedTrainDataset)  // note: patchedTrainDataset

// onehot and assemble
val oneHotEncoder = new OneHotEncoderEstimator().setInputCols(indexedCatFeatures).setOutputCols(indexedCatFeatures.map(_+KeyColumns.oneHotEncoderSuffix))
  .setDropLast(false)
val predictors = numFeatures ++ oneHotEncoder.getOutputCols
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(predictors).setOutputCol(KeyColumns.features)
val leftPipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(oneHotEncoder, assembler))

// feature transfomers
val transfomers = stringIndexerPipeline.asInstanceOf[PipelineModel].stages ++ leftPipeline.asInstanceOf[PipelineModel].stages

// train model
...

// 

val cv = new CrossValidator()
  .setEstimator(modelPipeline)
  .setEvaluator(new BinaryClassificationEvaluator().setLabelCol(KeyColumns.y))
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
  .setNumFolds(cvConfig.folders)
  .setParallelism(cvConfig.parallelism)

val transformedTrainDataset = leftPipeline.fit(strIndexTrainDataset).transform(strIndexTrainDataset)
val cvModel = cv.fit(transformedTrainDataset)

val bestModel = cvModel.bestModel.asInstanceOf[PipelineModel]
val newStages = transfomers ++ Array[SparkTransformer](bestModel.stages.last)

// !!!error  can't new here
val newBestModel = new PipelineModel(bestModel.uid, newStages) 
// !!!error  can't new here
val newCvModel = new CrossValidatorModel(cvModel.uid, newBestModel, cvModel.avgMetrics)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising a great question.

According to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53269590/17707800), we've known that you wouldn't get an instance of `PipelineModel` from `new` method (which is not legal for ). There are mainly two ways:

- `PipelineModel.load(file: String)`
- `val pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(dataFrame)`

Now here is the thing: **you can skip the `fit()` implicitly by only adding trained Model into `pipeline` to get `pipelineModel`.**

e.g.

```
// Still, add your trained models into a array
val trainedModels = cols.map(col => {
  new ValueIndexerModel().setInputCol(col).setOutputCol(col + "_indexed").setLevels(level)
})

// just set your models as stages of a pipeline as usual
val pipeline = new PipeLine().setStages(trainedModels)

// fit, which will skip for models
val pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(dataFrame)

// then you get your pipelineModel, you can transform now
val transDF = pipelineModel.transform(dataFrame)
```

The reason we are able to handle it like this is according to [the source code of spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5264164a67df498b73facae207eda12ee133be7d/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/Pipeline.scala#L154-L155):

```
val transformers = ListBuffer.empty[Transformer]
theStages.view.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (stage, index) =>
  if (index <= indexOfLastEstimator) {
    val transformer = stage match {
      case estimator: Estimator[_] =>
        estimator.fit(curDataset)
      case t: Transformer =>
        t
      case _ =>
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          s"Does not support stage $stage of type ${stage.getClass}")
    }
    if (index < indexOfLastEstimator) {
      curDataset = transformer.transform(curDataset)
    }
    transformers += transformer
  } else {
    transformers += stage.asInstanceOf[Transformer]
  }
}
```

Your trained model is subclass of `Transformer`, so when `fit`, your pipeline of trained models will skip all the process of `fit`, and give a pipelineModel with your trained models. Thanks to [zero323 and user1269298 in Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53269590/17707800) again.